# How to read Degree Minute Seconds (DMS) data directly from a .CSV file using pandas into a dataframe as strings?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

How to read Degree Minute Seconds (DMS) data directly from a .CSV file using  pandas into a dataframe as strings?
For eg:
If I have a csv file with a column of data that is in DMS format,How to read it to a dataframe as string for further calculations?

```
76° 17' 51.2399" E
77° 26' 30.8322" E
76° 51' 29.7812" E
75° 45' 41.3540" E
76° 17' 51.2399" E
```

input file sample :[enter link description here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/adda06f30d78ed308d510669b1c21ff120200525153241/6910f5)

When I use pandas.read_csv('test.csv) #test.csv is the input file
I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-90-2af7440e7795>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\obspy\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\obspy\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\obspy\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\obspy\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\obspy\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 529, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 749, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Comment: What is so specific about the data that you cannot use `pandas.read_csv()`?

Comment: Why isn't this being read as a string? What is your delimiter?

Comment: Somehow pandas.read_csv() giving an error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 5: invalid start byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file:

```
id,string
1,76° 17' 51.2399" E
2,77° 26' 30.8322" E
3,76° 51' 29.7812" E
4,75° 45' 41.3540" E
5,76° 17' 51.2399" E
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)

   id              string
0   1  76° 17' 51.2399" E
1   2  77° 26' 30.8322" E
2   3  76° 51' 29.7812" E
3   4  75° 45' 41.3540" E
4   5  76° 17' 51.2399" E
```

Can you share a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: I am getting an error and i am adding that error as an edit

Comment: Share sample of your CSV

Comment: can you try using `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')`
And `encoding='unicode-escape'`

Comment: encoding works, even though instead of ```76°``` it is showing ```76ø```

Answer (score 1):

Try using different encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', encoding='windows-1252')
```

Comment: encoding works, even though
instead of ```76°``` it is showing ```76ø```

Comment: @VGB try to test different encodings, that should help. How do you get your file? That can help with choosing correct encoding for your case.